# ScrollView height is determined before glide loads image into ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, android-glide

I am using Glide to load an image from the web into an ImageView which is part of a layout, defining an item inside a ListView.
The process is done inside the list's adapter's "getView" function.

The issue is that the scrollview height seems to be determined before the glide downloads the image, and then when the image is downloaded it is impossible to scroll down to see the whole image since the scrollview height wraps the content as it was before the image was loaded.

The adapter code as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // Get the data item for this position
    NewsBlockInfo newsBlockInfo = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        viewHolder.txtBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_body);
        viewHolder.imageExtra = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_extra);
        // Cache the viewHolder object inside the fresh view
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Populate the data from the data object via the viewHolder object
    // into the template view.
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(newsBlockInfo.Title);
    viewHolder.txtBody.setText(newsBlockInfo.Body);
    Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(newsBlockInfo.ImageUrl)
            .into(viewHolder.imageExtra);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

The item layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/news_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    ...

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_body"
    ...

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_extra"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#BBDEFB"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment layout xml:

```
 <ListView
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/news_list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     tools:context="haggaidev.nationui.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

 </ListView>
```

Is there any way to "refresh" the scrollview to re-wrap the content?

Comment: Why would you put just a single listview inside a scrollview? I guess there is no need to use the scrollview if you do not have another view inside it

Comment: Hey Haggai, As an idea, you can receive the image info within callback, and maybe then you could set a new width and height to your image view.

Comment: Every figure this out? I don't want to hard-code any height. So I can't exactly use a placeholder to have scrollview size itself. Also can't use callback, because Glide won't call them if the view doesn't appear (no size).